# OpenCV sets wrong camera resolution on frame capture

Tags: opencv, frame, video-capture

I'm trying to use OpenCV with python to capture a `1080p` frame from a USB camera.

I'm sure that the camera works at `1080p` because I tested it using `QTv4l2 Test Utils` and with that tool I can capture frames at the desired resolution.

However, running this code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)         #0 because I'm reading frames from /dev/video0
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
retval, frame = cam.read()
if retval != True:
    raise ValueError("Can't read frame")

cv2.imwrite('img2.png', frame)
cv2.imshow("img1", frame)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Creates a png image with resolution `640x480`.

Moreover, after executing `cv2.VideoCapture(3)`, if I open `QTv4l2 Test Utils` the possibility to set the camera resolution at 1080p is gone. The only way to get it back is to unplug and plug again the camera.

Any clue about why this happens and any suggestion about how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please do not use bare numbers, such as `cam.set(3,x)`, when OpenCV defines  everything you need for you here https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c It makes code hard to read, hard to maintain and encourages other folks to write sloppy code which breaks when constants are redefined in upgrades and ports.

Comment: I modified the question as you suggested